# Actionscript 3: Check an array for a match

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, match

If you have an array with six numbers, say:

```
public var check:Array = new Array[10,12,5,11,9,4];
```

or

```
public var check:Array = new Array[10,10,5,11,9,4];
```

How do you check for a match (of a pair?)

Comment: does the index of elements matters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array` class has an [`indexOf` method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#indexOf()):

> `function indexOf(searchElement:*, fromIndex:int = 0):int`
>
> Searches for an item in an array by using strict equality (===) and returns the index position of the item.
>
> Parameters
>
> - `searchElement:*` — The item to find in the array.
> - `fromIndex:int` (default = 0) — The location in the array from which to start searching for the item.
>
> Returns
>
> - int — A zero-based index position of the item in the array. If the `searchElement` argument is not found, the return value is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Got it (I think). Used the following:

```
public var match:Array = [10,12,5,10,9,4];

   checkArray(match);

   private function checkArray(check:Array) {

    var i:int;
    var j:int;

    for (i= 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        for (j= i+1; j < check.length; j++) {
            if (check[i] === check[j]) {
                trace(check[i] + " at " + i + " is a match with "+check[j] + " at " + j);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```