# FQL query isn't retrieving all the friends from the same University

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, action, facebook-fql

I am building an app which has a feature which requires all the user's friends who go to the same university to be called.

Here is the FQL query I am using:

```
SELECT name, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND ('110692668958084' IN education OR '103797159658620' IN education OR '330980680328922' IN education)
```

The reason for the many different school IDs is because there seems to be several different pages being used for the same university.

The problem with the query is that it only returns 8 or 9 friends (even less without all the other school IDs). Using the API explorer I have checked friends that do go to the same university and have not been returned by the query ( about 20+ ). I can confirm that all these friends have the same school IDs in their education attributes as the query above.

My question is: how come the query won't return all of them? is it something to do with user's privacy settings or is there something wrong with my query?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be better off getting all your friends with something in their `education` field and filtering it on your end.

Comment: you mean just get all my friends whilst adding 'education' to the SELECT clause, and then just fiter them inside the app on the client side? so this: `SELECT name, uid, pic_square, education FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`?

Comment: Yes. See if that gives you a more reliable result.

Comment: Im doing this in actionscript3: is there a way I can check for keywords in an object, without having to iterate through every persons education object? For example, could I just put an IF statement that checks the friend object and all of the fields inside the objects within that object? Going to try the 'hasOwnProperty()'

Comment: I've never worked in AS3, but this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046364/actionscript-3-check-an-array-for-a-match

Comment: I did a call for all of my friends, checked the incoming object on facebook and can see that the education fields are simply empty (of length 0). So I guess this is just a User's setting?

Comment: Are you requesting the `friends_education_history` permission in your access token?

Comment: yes, I am getting some of the user's education fields but most are returning with 0 length

Comment: Yes. Those users are either not setting their education, or they've set their privacy settings such that you can't get them via an api call.

Comment: is there a way i can implement a change to that inside the app? like a link to their privacy settings? (if they were using the app)

Comment: No. A user has the preference to block all apps from getting at their personal data.